# Float formatting in Python

Tags: python, formatting

While doing this exercise:

```
>>> amount = 24.325    
>>> print("%7f" % amount)
>>> 24.325000
```

I didn't understand why instead of printing ' 24.325' (whith 1 space before the number) it just added three '0' and didn't move it towards the right at all.

So I thought that maybe, when you don't specify the precision, Python adds '0' until the number has at least 6 digits after the decimal point (if it doesn't already have them) and THAN takes in consideration the width I set (in this case, 7) and adds the needed spaces. In the exercise, with the extra '0's, it ends up having 9 digits, so it didn't add any. Is my hypothesis correct?

The question is, why 6 digits after the decimal point? Is it something that Python does by default?

Thank you.

Comment: try this `print("%.3f" % amount)`

Answer (score 2):

The [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) exactly describe how the formatting operator `%` works.

In particular, you can have a minimum field with an a precision.

The former defines the minimum length of your resulting string, the latter gives the number of digits after the decimal point.

As the default precision is 6 for `%f`, you get what you get.